# ¿Como obtener el ID del div padre al hacer clic en cualquier de sus hijos?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un `div` padre con un ID que deseo capturar.

Este `div` padre funciona solo como contenedor y almacena dentro de él 2 div hijos que muestran:

- El primero una imagen
- El segundo un título.

Quiero obtener el `ID` del `div` padre al hacer `clic` sobre cualquier de los 2 div hijos, pero no puedo, ya que cuando hago `clic` me detecta los `ID` de los `div` hijos (*sea de la imagen o del título*) y no del padre.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target.matches('.div-padre'))
    console.log(e.target.id);
});
```

```css
.div-padre {
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div-hijo-1 {
  height: 130px;
}

.div-hijo-1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
}

.div-hijo-2 {
  height: 28px;
  padding: 6px 5px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div id="comprador-plus" class="div-padre">

  <div class="div-hijo-1">

    <img src="compradores/Andres/foto.png">

  </div>

  <div class="div-hijo-2">

    <div>
      <span>Andres</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <span>Plus</span>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué agregar un evento _a todo el documento_ en lugar de usar `querySelector`?

Comment: @padaleiana Porque tengo varios div padre con la misma clase pero diferente id cada uno al imprimir la pagina completa

Comment: Claro, pero también existe `querySelectorAll`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagino que la idea es lograr algo similar a la [delegación de eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events), pero me parece que no es exactamente la misma idea.

Una forma de llegar a lo que estás buscando es la siguiente:

- Con [`Event.composedPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath) devuelve un arreglo de los elementos del DOM recorridos, desde donde se origino el evento hasta llegar al elemento donde se capturo.
- Con [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) recorremos el arreglo hasta encontrar el primer elemento del DOM que coincida con nuestra condición.
- Con [`Element.classList.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) preguntamos si el elemento contiene la clase `div-padre`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  const nodes = e.composedPath(),
    element = nodes.find(node => node.classList?.contains('div-padre'));
  console.log(element ? element.id : false);
});
```

```css
.div-padre {
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div-hijo-1 {
  height: 130px;
}

.div-hijo-1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
}

.div-hijo-2 {
  height: 28px;
  padding: 6px 5px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div id="comprador-plus" class="div-padre">
  <div class="div-hijo-1">
    <img src="compradores/Andres/foto.png">
  </div>
  <div class="div-hijo-2">
    <div>
      <span>Andres</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Plus</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="comprador-plus-2" class="div-padre">
  <div class="div-hijo-1">
    <img src="compradores/Andres/foto.png">
  </div>
  <div class="div-hijo-2">
    <div>
      <span>Andres</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Plus</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó perfectamente! :)

Answer (score 0):

El código actual captura el evento de clic en los divs hijos antes que en el div padre, lo que puede funcionar es tratarlo de manera diferente a como está sucediendo.

Una forma de hacerlo es:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const divPadre = e.target.parentNode;
    //console.log(divPadre)
    if (divPadre && divPadre.classList.contains('div-padre'))
      console.log(divPadre.id);
  });
```

```css
.div-padre {
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div-hijo-1 {
  height: 130px;
}

.div-hijo-1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
}

.div-hijo-2 {
  height: 28px;
  padding: 6px 5px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div id="comprador-plus" class="div-padre">

  <div class="div-hijo-1">

    <img src="compradores/Andres/foto.png">

  </div>

  <div class="div-hijo-2">

    <div>
      <span>Andres</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <span>Plus</span>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

divPadre, nó padre. en `classList` devuelve una lista de clases y el uso de la función `contains('div-padre')` verificará si en la lista de clases hay `div-padre`, el uso del operador lógico **AND** devolverá `true` si las expresiones son verdaderas. `divPadre && divPadre.classList.contains('div-padre')`

Answer (score 0):

- Espero te sea util
- 
- He creado una función llamada ParentNode que evalua cada elemento verificando que su clase sea la indicada
- 
- estoy manejando el evento con la propiedad matches para asegurarme que estoy clicando un elemento valido
- y estoy llamando la función ParentNode con los parametros correspondientes
- 
- de esta forma creando código reutilizable y optimizando el código
- 
- y todo funciona 10/10

```js
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if (e.target.matches('.div-padre *')){
        //A la constante padre le asigno el valor devuelto por la funcion ParentNode
        const padre = ParentNode(e.target,'div-padre')
        //verifico que padre sea el elemento
        if(padre){console.log(padre.id)}
    }
  });

  function ParentNode(nodo=document.body,clas=''){
    let node = nodo
    while(!node.classList.contains(clas)){
        if(node.nodeName == 'BODY'){return false}
        node = node.parentElement
    }
    return node
  }
```

```css
.div-padre {
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .div-hijo-1 {
    height: 130px;
  }
  
  .div-hijo-1 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center center;
  }
  
  .div-hijo-2 {
    height: 28px;
    padding: 6px 5px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="comprador-plus" class="div-padre">

        <div class="div-hijo-1">
      
          <img src="https://img.freepik.com/fotos-premium/colegial-triste-imagen-3d-fondo-colorido-ai-generativo_58409-28910.jpg">
      
        </div>
      
        <div class="div-hijo-2">
      
          <div>
            <span>Andres</span>
          </div>
      
          <div>
            <span>Plus</span>
          </div>
      
        </div>
      
      </div>

      <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```